# Trouble displaying a custom marker using gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

This gem is awesome for displaying a dynamic map.  I am a beginner programmer, and I cannot seem to get a custom marker to display on the map.

I have the following in my model:

```
def gmaps4rails_marker_picture
       {
        "picture" => 'images/logo_avatar.png',
         "width" =>  '16',        
         "height" => '16'
         }
  end
```

I have tried many combinations of the info provided in the github README, but to no avail.  My map works perfectly until the above code gets plugged into the model....then all the markers go away.  Is the sidebar code required in order to display a custom marker?

Here is one version of what I have in the controller:

```
@markers = Property.where(:id => propertyids).to_gmaps4rails
```

and the view:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@markers) %>
```

I have tried passing in the image as an option, but could not get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure why view didn't show up above:

Comment: I don't understand the problem here. What error do you have from your js debugger?

Comment: checking the js debugger was a great idea....it is not finding my .png file.  It is looking at localhost:3000/images/logo_avatar.png.  I have tried changing the path in the model to:  app/assets/images/logo_avatar.png but it is still not finding the image.  I have also tried moving the image to just inside the project directory.....any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

At the controller level, do:

```
@json = Property.where(:id => propertyids).to_gmaps4rails do |property, marker|
  marker.picture({
    "picture" => path_to_image('/images/logo_avatar.png'),
     "width" =>  '16',        
     "height" => '16'
     })
end
```

It lets you use the assets tag helper.

Comment: wow, you are quick.  I am now getting this error:  undefined method `path_to_image' for #<ListingsController:0x007fde5052a018>.  Is this because the Property.rb model has the acts_as_gmappable declaration?.  Property and Listing have a has_many belongs_to relationship.  The Property model has the address, but the map is displayed in the Listings index view.

Comment: I see now that path_to_image is not related to gmaps4rails.  I am researching how to load assets tag helpers in development environment.

Comment: I tried changing path_to_image to asset_path, now I get an error 'wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)' that references line 113 which is the 'picture' => asset_path('logo_avatar.png') line.  I removed the  file name and parentheses......no errors, but the final view shows the original map markers.  I am 4 weeks into programming, so my apologies on the amateurish comments....but any help would be mucho appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hey tbone I think I was having a similar issue and found the solution,
all I did was change it to this

```
marker.picture({
                  'picture' => view_context.image_path("green-dot.png"),
                  'width'   => 32,
                  'height'  => 32
                 })
```

Answer (score 0):

the following code works for me, try it..

```
@json = Property.where(:id => propertyids).to_gmaps4rails do |property, marker|
  marker.picture({
    "picture" => 'assets/logo_avatar.png',
     "width" =>  '16',        
     "height" => '16'
     })
end
```