# Custom Marker in gmaps4rails won't appear

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmaps4rails

I tried following the guide in https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails, however my custom icons still do not load.

```
 @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@terminals) do |terminal, marker|
          marker.lat terminal.latitude
          marker.lng terminal.longitude
         marker.picture({
            "url" => "/assets/marker.png",
            "width" =>  30,        
            "height" => 30
            })
        end
```

The image marker.png is in assets/images.

Building the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(13);
  handler.getMap().setOptions({styles: [{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"saturation":43},{"lightness":-11},{"hue":"#0088ff"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"hue":"#ff0000"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":99}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#808080"},{"lightness":54}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ece2d9"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ccdca1"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#767676"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b8cb93"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.medical","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]}]});
});
</script>
```

The map:

```
    <div id="map"class="col-md-8" style="height: 100vh; background-color: #E4E2E1;">
    </div>
```

How it appears:
[image]

How it looks without marker.picture in the controller:
[image]

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498760/trouble-displaying-a-custom-marker-using-gmaps4rails) if it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `marker.picture` to:

```
marker.picture({
   url: ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('marker.png'),
   width:  '30',        
   height: '30'
})
```